# AngularJS Get Status error details $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new angularJS student, and i want to get detail error's when i send a POST to WebApi.
I want to get Status 500 and Status 404, and make condition to show a feedback instead of the status error.

I have tried use "Intercepting HTTP calls with AngularJS", but everytime it returns 'Status -1'

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

@EDIT

```
.factory('ajaxFn', function ($http, $cookies, $location, $q) {

    var post = function (url, objeto, data, successFn, errorFn) {
        user = $cookies.get(btoa('user'));
        pass = $cookies.get(btoa('pass'));
        authHeader.Authorization = 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ':' + pass);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "//localhost:61115/api/main/" + CompleteUrl,
            headers: authHeader,
            params: objeto,
            data: data
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            successFn(result.data);
        }, function (data) {
            errorFn();
        });
    }
    return {
        post: post
    };
})
```

---

And that is the intercepting code that i have tried

// Intercepting HTTP calls with AngularJS.
    .config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {

```
    // Intercept http calls.
    $provide.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
        return {
            // On request success
            request: function (config) {
                // console.log(config); // Contains the data about the request before it is sent.

                // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            // On request failure
            requestError: function (rejection) {
                // console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            // On response success
            response: function (response) {
                // console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.

                // Return the response or promise.
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            // On response failture
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                // console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });

    // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider.
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');

})
```

Comment: We might be able help if you showed us some code.

Comment: Sounds like the connection is not being made, code would definitely help. Also, are you connected to the internet in order to hit the service?

Comment: I don't know what kind of code i can show... i updated my question with my POST code